# Hide title when input is expanded, show title when input is minimized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design

I have a sample code that is displaying a search query with css animation.

I would like to know, how can I hide the 'title' class when the search query is expanded, and show it again when the search query is minimized?

Here is a sample image of the two states (as you can see 'title' is viewable behind the search text, which I dont want):

[image]

I know that within the jquery I can hide it like so (showing it again I don't know how the logic would go):

```
$("p").hide();
```

but how can I do it with just CSS?

The snippet is working, but its not displaying correctly, though I dont know why.

```js
$('.opener').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.search').toggleClass('inactive').find('input').focus();
});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  /*background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);*/
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-radius: 2px;*/
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);*/
}

.input-group:active,
.input-group:hover {
  /*background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);*/
}

.input-group.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.input-group .input-group-addon {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 36px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}

.input-group .input-group-addon i {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  align-self: center;
  color: #777;
}

.input-group input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
}

.inactive {
  width: 36px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.inactive .input-group-addon:not(:first-child) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300|Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <h1>Search Inputs</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="input-group search inactive pull-right">
            <span class="input-group-addon opener">
              <i class="material-icons">search</i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            <span class="input-group-addon opener">
              <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**siblings**](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select the `div.title`.
Add another class for with display:none property and toggle that class

```js
$("p").hide();
$('.opener').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.search').toggleClass('inactive').find('input').focus();
  $(this).parent('.search').siblings('div.title').toggleClass('hideTitle')
});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  /*background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);*/
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-radius: 2px;*/
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);*/
}

.input-group:active,
.input-group:hover {
  /*background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);*/
}

.input-group.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.input-group .input-group-addon {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 36px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}

.input-group .input-group-addon i {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  align-self: center;
  color: #777;
}

.input-group input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
}

.inactive {
  width: 36px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.inactive .input-group-addon:not(:first-child) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.hideTitle{
 display:none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300|Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1>Search Inputs</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="title titleDiv">Title</div>
    <div class="input-group search inactive pull-right">
      <span class="input-group-addon opener">
    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
   </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

      <span class="input-group-addon opener">
    <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
   </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok the question was not clear whether you want hide the entire block. You mentioned `hide title class`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap label and input in one div with position relative and used [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) jquery to hide the title

```js
$('.opener').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.search').toggleClass('inactive').find('input').focus();
  $(this).parent('.search').siblings('label').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.search-form {
  position:relative;
}

.search-form .title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  /*background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);*/
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-radius: 2px;*/
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);*/
}

.input-group:active,
.input-group:hover {
  /*background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);*/
}

.input-group.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.input-group .input-group-addon {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 36px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}

.input-group .input-group-addon i {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  align-self: center;
  color: #777;
}

.input-group input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
}

.inactive {
  width: 36px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.inactive .input-group-addon:not(:first-child) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300|Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <h1>Search Inputs</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="search-form">
          <label class="title">Title</label>
          <div class="input-group search inactive pull-right">
              <span class="input-group-addon opener">
                <i class="material-icons">search</i>
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              <span class="input-group-addon opener">
                <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
              </span>
          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great, thank you :) ...Do you know why my snippet is not displaying correctly though? I dont know whether I am missing something from my codepen example: https://codepen.io/krystyna93/pen/GOjqBp?editors=1100

Comment: All works fine, just you forgot to hide the title div

Comment: I just meant my snippet overall is not looking like my codepen example

Comment: ahh, @Minal Chauhan, okay. So am I suppose to overwrite it?